# Yajra Datatables with custom buttons

Tags: laravel, vue.js, yajra-datatable

I am using the Yajra Datatables  with server side rendering in a Laravel project. But I want to add some custom buttons to the columns that will have Vue @click functions. I am trying to add like this but the click it's not working.

```
      ->addColumn('action', function($user){
        $btn = '<a @click="delete_user('.$user->id.')"><i class="fa fa-times font-20 deleteUser"></i></a>';
       
        return $btn;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `v-on:click` in code. Can you please show the vue js code.

Answer (score 0):

This is on my controller, other js functions like copying the passw and loging as user are working fine. The only thing not working is Vue click:

```php
public function getBasicData()
    {

        $user=User::all();
        return Datatables::of(User::query())
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('view_user', function($user){
                $btn =
                    '<a href="http://account.com/admin/client/'.$user->id.'">'.$user->name.'</a>';
                return $btn;
            })

            ->addColumn('action', function($user){

                if(Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $user->id))
                    $btn3='<i class="fa fa-circle font-16 onlineStatus online"></i>';
                else $btn3 ='<i class="far fa-circle font-16 onlineStatus offline"></i>';

                $btn1 = '<a v-on:click="delete_user('.$user->id.')"><i class="fa fa-times font-20 deleteUser"></i></a>';
                $btn2 = '<a href="http://account.com/login_user/'.$user->id.'"><i class="fa fa-user font-20"></i></a><input id="myInput'.$user->id.'" class="copyPassInput" value="'.$user->real_password.'"><i onclick="myFunction('.$user->id.')" title="'.$user->real_password.'" class="fa fa-eye  font-20 copyPassIcon"></i>';
                $btn4='<div class="d-flex">'.$btn2.' '.$btn1.' '.$btn3.'</div>';


                return $btn4;
            })

            ->rawColumns(['view_user','action'])
            ->make();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, I do not want to reboot to the ease of working with Yajra or to the power of Vue. I have fixed it by calling the function directly from the Vue instantiated object.

```
<button id="btn_entrada_edit" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-item text-primary" onclick="modal_edit_entrada.edit_entrada(' . $entrada->id . ')" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Editar</button>
```